# How can I keep fit whilst having tendonopathy in my glute?

Tags: tendons, glutes

I have tendonopathy in both my glutes but especially my right one.
If I can’t do running for a while and Bigg impact things, how do I keep fit and still do cardio?
Can I do any HIiT workouts still?
I don’t want to lose fitness and muscle tone!

Comment: High volume, low weight resistance training with short rest to emphasise CV exercise, or something like a hand cycling machine.